# How to Develop a Successful Sitemap

Tags: seo, sitemap, web

I have been browsing around on the internet and researching effective sitemap web pages. I have encountered these two sitemaps and questioning their effectiveness.

http://www.webanswers.com/sitemap/

http://www.answerbag.com/sitemap/

Are these sitemaps effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff Atwood, (One of the guys who made this site) wrote a great article on the [importance of sitemaps](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001174.html).

> I'm a little aggravated that we have
> to set up this special file for the
> Googlebot to do its job properly; it
> seems to me that web crawlers should
> be able to spider down our simple
> paging URL scheme without me giving
> them an explicit assist.
>
> The good news is that since we set up
> our sitemaps.xml, every question on
> Stack Overflow is eminently findable.
> But when 50% of your traffic comes
> from one source, perhaps it's best not
> to ask these kinds of questions.

So yeah, effective for people, or effective for google?

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought a HTML sitemap should be useful to a human, whereas these 2 sites aren't.  If you're trying to target a search engine then a sitemap.xml file that conforms to [sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/) would be a better approach.  Whilst the html approach would work it's easier to generate a xml file and have your robots.txt file pointing at this.